# How to auto-reboot buildslave hosts after builder finished?

Tags: windows, buildbot

I use Buildbot 0.8.7p1 and want to reboot servers after build has finished.
I tried interlocks, shutdown step - nothing helped.

In case of buildstep - if I reboot server or just force to stop slave - build receive exception.. Ideally to use some sort 'graceful shutdown + reboot' at the start of build (first buildstep), so after build on current builder will be finished - server goes down..

Answer (score 1):

I use a rebooting buildstep on some of my Windows slaves to test multiple versions of Windows installed on the same machine.

Adding a step calling "shutdown /f /r /t 30" works for me without causing an exception, e.g.:

```
f.addStep(ShellCommand(name="Rebooting",command="shutdown /f /r /t 30"))
```

where `f` is the `buildfactory`.